# Integrating hyperledger explorer in hyperledger fabric 2.2.0, facing issue while enrolling client failed to create wallet

Tags: postgresql, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

Using BAF, I have setup fabric 2.2.0 with 6 orgs and 1 orderer in a kubernetes cluster. Each org has one peer. Now I am trying to integrate Explorer v1.1.2 with nodejs v12.16.0 apline3.11, postgresql v10 by creating separate pod for explorer and postgresql. I am facing the following issue while starting the explorer app (main.js)

```
[2020-12-10T01:44:56.894] [DEBUG] main - false ssl-certs /opt/explorer/ssl-certs
[2020-12-10T01:44:56.995] [INFO] PgService - SSL to Postgresql disabled
[2020-12-10T01:44:56.995] [INFO] PgService - connecting to Postgresql postgres://hppoc:******@explorerdb:5432/fabricexplorer
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.621] [DEBUG] Platform - ******* Initialization started for hyperledger fabric platform ******
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.622] [DEBUG] Platform - ******* Initialization started for hyperledger fabric platform ******, {
  Bankema: { name: 'Bankema', profile: './connection-profile/Bankema.json' }
}
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.622] [DEBUG] Platform - Setting admin organization enrolment files
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.622] [INFO] Platform -  client_configs.name  Bankema  client_configs.profile  ./connection-profile/Bankema.json
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.622] [DEBUG] Platform - Creating client [Bankema] >>  { name: 'Bankema', profile: './connection-profile/Bankema.json' }
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.623] [DEBUG] User - User : admin
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.646] [INFO] Platform - Already registered : admin
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.647] [DEBUG] FabricUtils - ************ Initializing fabric client for [Bankema]************
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.647] [DEBUG] FabricClient - Client configuration [Bankema]  ...  this.client_config  { name: 'Bankema', profile: './connection-profile/Bankema.json' }
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.648] [INFO] FabricConfig - config.client.tlsEnable  true
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.648] [DEBUG] FabricGateway - LOADING CONFIGURATION  [OBJECT OBJECT]
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.648] [INFO] FabricConfig - FabricConfig, this.config.channels  bankemachannel
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.756] [INFO] FabricGateway - enrollUserIdentity: userName : admin
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.923] **[ERROR] FabricGateway - TypeError: org.peers is not iterable
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.924] [ERROR] FabricClient - ExplorerError: [
  'Failed to create wallet, please check the configuration, and valid file paths'
]
    at FabricGateway.initialize (/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/gateway/FabricGateway.js:135:10)
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.925] [ERROR]** main - <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[2020-12-10T01:44:57.925] [ERROR] main - Error :  [ 'Invalid platform configuration, Please check the log' ]
[2020-12-10T01:44:59.926] [INFO] main - Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully
[2020-12-10T01:44:59.927] [INFO] main - Closed out connections
```

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this? This is the connection profile which I am using

```html
`{
    "name": "Bankema",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "tlsEnable": true,
        "caCredential": {
            "id": "bankema-admin",
            "password": "bankema-adminpw"
        },
        "adminCredential": {
            "id": "exploreradmin",
            "password": "exploreradminpw"
        },
        "enableAuthentication": true,
        "organization": "bankema",
        "channel": ["bankemachannel"]
    },
    "channels": {
        "bankemachannel": {
            "peers": {
                "peer0.bankema-net": {
                    "ledgerQuery": true
                },
                "peer0.vendor-net": {
                    "ledgerQuery": true
                },
                "peer0.factor-net": {
                    "ledgerQuery": true
                },
                "peer0.corg-net": {
                    "ledgerQuery": true
                },
                "peer0.insurer-net": {
                    "ledgerQuery": true
                },
                "peer0.investor3-net": {
                    "ledgerQuery": true
                }
            },
            "orderers": {
                "orderer1.ordorg-net": {}
            },
            "connection": {
                "timeout": {
                    "peer": {
                        "endorser": "6000",
                        "eventHub": "6000",
                        "eventReg": "6000"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "bankema": {
            "mspid": "bankemaMSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.bankema-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.bankema-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/bankema-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/bankema-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        },
        "bankemaMSP": {
            "mspid": "bankemaMSP",
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordorg-net/orderers/orderer1.ordorg-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            }
        },
        "vendor": {
            "mspid": "vendorMSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.vendor-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.vendor-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/vendor-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/vendor-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        },
        "vendorMSP": {
            "mspid": "vendorMSP",
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordorg-net/orderers/orderer1.ordorg-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            }
        },
        "factor": {
            "mspid": "factorMSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.factor-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.factor-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/factor-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/factor-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        },
        "factorMSP": {
            "mspid": "factorMSP",
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordorg-net/orderers/orderer1.ordorg-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            }
        },
        "corg": {
            "mspid": "corgMSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.corg-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.corg-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/corg-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/corg-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        },
        "corgMSP": {
            "mspid": "corgMSP",
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordorg-net/orderers/orderer1.ordorg-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            }
        },
        "insurer": {
            "mspid": "insurerMSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.insurer-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.insurer-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/insurer-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/insurer-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        },
        "insurerMSP": {
            "mspid": "insurerMSP",
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordorg-net/orderers/orderer1.ordorg-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            }
        },
        "investor3": {
            "mspid": "investor3MSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.investor3-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.investor3-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/investor3-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/investor3-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        },
        "investor3MSP": {
            "mspid": "investor3MSP",
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordorg-net/orderers/orderer1.ordorg-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.bankema-net": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/bankema-net/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.crt"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://peer0.bankema-net:7051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.bankema-net"
            }
        },
        "peer0.vendor-net": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/vendor-net/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.crt"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://peer0.vendor-net:7051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.vendor-net"
            }
        },
        "peer0.factor-net": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/factor-net/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.crt"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://peer0.factor-net:7051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.factor-net"
            }
        },
        "peer0.corg-net": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/corg-net/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.crt"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://peer0.corg-net:7051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.corg-net"
            }
        },
        "peer0.insurer-net": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/insurer-net/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.crt"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://peer0.insurer-net:7051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.insurer-net"
            }
        },
        "peer0.investor3-net": {
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/investor3-net/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.crt"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://peer0.investor3-net:7051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.investor3-net"
            }
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer1.ordorg-net": {
            "url": "grpcs://orderer1.ordorg-net:7050",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer1.ordorg-net"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordorg-net/orderers/orderer1.ordorg-net/tls/ca.crt"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.bankema-net": {
            "url": "https://ca.bankema-net:7054",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/bankema-net/ca/ca.bankema-net-cert.pem"
            },
            "registrar": {
                "enrollId": "bankema-admin",
                "enrollSecret": "bankema-adminpw"
            },

            "caName": "ca.bankema-net"
        },
        "ca.vendor-net": {
            "url": "https://ca.vendor-net:7054",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/vendor-net/ca/ca.vendor-net-cert.pem"
            },

            "caName": "ca.vendor-net"
        },
        "ca.factor-net": {
            "url": "https://ca.factor-net:7054",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/factor-net/ca/ca.factor-net-cert.pem"
            },

            "caName": "ca.factor-net"
        },
        "ca.corg-net": {
            "url": "https://ca.corg-net:7054",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/corg-net/ca/ca.corg-net-cert.pem"
            },

            "caName": "ca.corg-net"
        },
        "ca.insurer-net": {
            "url": "https://ca.insurer-net:7054",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/insurer-net/ca/ca.insurer-net-cert.pem"
            },

            "caName": "ca.insurer-net"
        },
        "ca.investor3-net": {
            "url": "https://ca.investor3-net:7054",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/investor3-net/ca/ca.investor3-net-cert.pem"
            },

            "caName": "ca.investor3-net"
        }
    },
    "configtxgenToolPath": "/mnt/fabric/fabric-samples/bin",
    "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

Comment: When posting questions, you need information about what documents you referred to and what you did in what circumstances.

Comment: [2020-12-10T01:44:57.646] [INFO] Platform - Already registered : admin
-> Is it correct to clean all artifacts before up the hyperledger-fabric?

Comment: [2020-12-10T01:44:57.924] [ERROR] FabricClient - ExplorerError: [
  'Failed to create wallet, please check the configuration, and valid file paths'
] -> could you check configuration & file paths?

Comment: If you check it, the information on the configuration and the development environment are also different.

Comment: I refered the following docs - https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/tree/v1.1.2, https://medium.com/coinmonks/blockchain-explorer-integration-with-hyperledger-fabric-fc14570753f7#, https://medium.com/@blocksnchain/quick-integration-of-hyperledger-explorer-with-fabric-2-2-2-using-docker-19473aed95d7.

Comment: I have a doubt. For adminprivatekey and signcerts, I have the key file in the format server.key and server.crt instead of the certificate that ends with _sk and .pem. Does hyperledger explorer supports any format file? @myeongkilkim

Comment: The file format doesn't matter. It is important that the configuration values in the connection profiles and the actual crypto-config exist in the path and match.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning existed artifacts before network up?

Comment: No I didn't clear. It is a live environment (production cluster setup). I kept the crypto material in the mounted directory. Does the explorer take full path?

Comment: As I said earlier, edit the question. Should give us more information.

Comment: See below for a guide to the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You already know that you tried without clearing now. What I am curious about is the log and result after clearing and trying.

Comment: Also, if you look at the generated ERROR log, it appears that the configuration is wrong. In particular, it seems that a problem has occurred in org.peers, and it is presumed to have occurred because the data is empty.

Comment: However, these are all estimates.
You must upload the configuration to check.

Comment: Give the connection profile (json) file written in explorer

Comment: Can you please check the connection profile I have modified my question

Answer (score 0):

Organizations seem to be wrong. The `peers` key is required.
ref : [fabric/connection-profile](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/developapps/connectionprofile.html)

- bankemaMSP
- vendorMSP
- factorMSP
- corgMSP
- insurerMSP
- investor3MSP

What is the intention of the above part? If you see that the mspid has the same organization, it does not appear to be a separate organization, and it seems that it needs to be deleted.

Try to modify it as follows, See connection profile example

```json
{
    ~~~
    "organizations": {
        "bankema": {
            "mspid": "bankemaMSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.bankema-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.bankema-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/bankema-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/bankema-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        },
        "vendor": {
            "mspid": "vendorMSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.vendor-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.vendor-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/vendor-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/vendor-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        },
        "factor": {
            "mspid": "factorMSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.factor-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.factor-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/factor-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/factor-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        },
        "corg": {
            "mspid": "corgMSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.corg-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.corg-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/corg-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/corg-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        },
        "insurer": {
            "mspid": "insurerMSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.insurer-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.insurer-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/insurer-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/insurer-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        },
        "investor3": {
            "mspid": "investor3MSP",
            "peers": {
                "peer0.investor3-net": {}
            },
            "certificateAuthorities": {
                "ca.investor3-net": {}
            },
            "fullpath": true,
            "adminPrivateKey": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/investor3-net/msp/keystore/server.key"
            },
            "signedCert": {
                "path": "/mnt/fabric/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/investor3-net/msp/signcerts/server.crt"
            }
        }
    }
    ~~~
}
```